# How to properly deploy a VSTO Outlook plugin, signed with a code certificate, through ClickOnce for Windows Defender acceptance?

Tags: clickonce, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, windows-defender

I have developed an Outlook plugin that is deployed to thousands of clients. Recently, some of our clients are having issues when we push out updates for the plugin.

The update is deployed on our servers, and ClickOnce handles the rest. However, our plugin is signed with a code certificate. It utilizes third-party libraries, and some DLLs are not signed. I've tried various methods to resolve this without success.

I tried creating a post-build event to sign the DLLs with our Code Signing certificate using the signtool.exe. Some DLLs (third-party ones) remained unsigned.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign /a /f  $(ProjectDir)\certificate.p7b  /t http://timestamp.digicert.com /fd SHA384  $(ProjectDir)bin\$(Configuration)\*.dll
```

I developed a PowerShell script that takes the .dll.deploy files, renames them to .dll, signs the unsigned DLLs, and then renames them back to .dll.deploy. Yet, I get an error stating that the DLLs listed in the ClickOnce manifest are incorrect.

```
$certPath = "C:\certificate.p7b"
$timestampUrl = "http://timestamp.digicert.com"
$hashAlgorithm = "SHA384"
$version = "23.06.20.3"
$outputDir = "C:\plugin\outlook\Application Files\MyOutlookApp_" + $version.Replace(".", "_")
Write-Host $outputDir
Get-ChildItem -Path $outputDir -Filter *.dll.deploy -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

    # Renaming .dll.deploy to .dll
    $dllFile = $_.FullName -replace ".deploy",""
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $dllFile

   # $dllFile = $outputDir +"\PhoneNumbers.dll"
    
    # Check if DLL is signed
   
    $signature = Get-AuthenticodeSignature $dllFile
    Write-Host $signature.Status
    if ($signature.Status -eq 'NotSigned') {
       Write-Host "sign the dll" + $dllFile
        & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign /a /f $certPath /t $timestampUrl /fd $hashAlgorithm $dllFile
    }else{
     # Write-Host "already sign the dll" + $dllFile
    }

    # Renaming .dll back to .dll.deploy
    Rename-Item $dllFile -NewName ($dllFile + ".deploy")
}
```

My issue is that Windows Defender deletes my files even before the ClickOnce plugin update download finishes.

I've also tried adding the certificate to the trusted publishers, but the problem persists.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to handle this?